# Can I pass information between a CodeActivity (workflow) and a Plugin using SharedVariables in Dynamics 365?

Tags: c#, plugins, workflow, microsoft-dynamics, shared-variable

I have a bespoke CodeActivity that gets called by an On Demand Workflow in Dynamics 365. The CodeActivity creates a new Quote which in turns triggers some Plugins that I have registered against the Create message.

I'm looking to prevent the plugins from firing if it's against the Quote created by my CodeActivity. The plugins should fire under all other circumstances.

I thought I could do it with [SharedVariables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/understand-the-data-context#shared-variables) in the context but I can't get it working. I've shared a basic snippet below demonstrating what I've done, however in my example `foundKey` is always false. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a different way to achieve this requirement?

**CodeActivity**

```
public sealed class CopyQuote : CodeActivity
{
    [Input("Quote")]
    [Default("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", "quote")]
    [ReferenceTarget("quote")]
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<EntityReference> Quote { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
    {
        var workflowContext = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
        workflowContext.SharedVariables.Add("MyUniqueKey","MyValue");

        // CODE THAT CREATES THE QUOTE IS HERE WHICH IS ALL SUCCESSFUL
    }
}
```

**Plugin**

```
public class CopyProductDetails : IPlugin
{
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var context = 
           (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

        // I TRY AND FIND THE SHAREDVARIABLE
        var foundKey = false;

        if (context.MessageName == "Create")
        {
            if (context.SharedVariables.ContainsKey("MyUniqueKey"))
            {
                    foundKey = true;
            }
            else
            {
                var parentContext = context.ParentContext;

                while (parentContext != null)
                {
                    if (parentContext.SharedVariables.ContainsKey("MyUniqueKey"))
                    {
                        foundKey = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    parentContext = parentContext.ParentContext;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

shared variables work on the same context (like from a Pre-Operation to a Post-Operation) not in a Parent-Child context (in your case the Parent is the workflow activity, the child is the plugin on Create).

You can check the content of context.ParentContext inside the plugin to see if you are able to find if the quote has been created from a workflow (and if all is synchronous the context.Depth should be 2 in your plugin)

However these are not reliable methods, I suggest you go for the simplest route: create a boolean field inside Quote entity and set it to true when the quote is created from the workflow. Inside the plugin you check if this field is true. It is also a good way to log the quotes created from your workflow activity.